# data from Gridview to textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a form with datagridview in vb.net that show my data in columns. what i'm trying to accomplish is that after choosing a row and pressing Edit button a new form will open and split the row for the right text boxes to update the data. the datagridview row shows different types of data: name,email,date,etc... any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the EditButton click-handler, you may access the selected row in your datagridview with the MyDataGridView.CurrentRow property.

This object - a DataGridViewRow - has Cells, which you can access individually by index and then get to their values:

...CurrentRow.Cells(n).Value

This then, in turn, you may use to fill the items in your edit form.

After completing your edit form, retrieve the (updated) values and put them back into the CurrentRow.Cells(n).Value

If your datagridview is databound, then you can also work directly with the datastore, through

...CurrentRow.DataBoundItem

The type of this object depends of course on your configuration; it may, for instance, be a DataRow.

This should be enough to get you going.

Final note on your added remark "thanks ...": you're apparently new at this site. I'm not sure why you got "downvotes". It may be because your question is rather elementary ("homework"), or people found your problem description not clear/detailed enough. Please, understand that answers (if any) are provided "unpaid for", and require "voluntary" effort from the contributors. Understandably they prefer that YOU do most of the work/study/trying, before asking someone else "to do your work for you". No offense intended.